# Using a literal suffix name when defining a static constexpr class member

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++-chrono

I'd like to define a `static constexpr` data member in a class, like

```
class my_protocol
{
public:
    static constexpr auto comm_timeout = 50ms;
    ...
};
```

Is there a good way to avoid the `using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;` at global scope in the header file that defines this class?

Comment: You can do it in your own namespace if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

There is still the lambda directly invoked way:

```
class my_protocol
{
public:
    static constexpr auto comm_timeout = [](){
        using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
        return 50ms;
    }();
    // ...
};
```